# Reactive k-means analysis on checkboxes Shiny R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have some data

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  lat = rnorm(150, mean = 30, sd = 5),
  lon = rnorm(150, mean = 10, sd = 5),
  iris[, 1:4]))
```

I have a UI that allows me to select columns/vars (not including lat and lon) based on those present in the DF through checkboxes from following this [excellent demo](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Selectable variables for k-means",
                         names(df[, 3:6]), selected = names(df[, 3:6])),
      numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9),
    ),
    # mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))))
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable1'))))
```

I can see this is working with the following

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #### choose columns to display
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**What I want to do in the following order**

**1 - Run k-means analysis on the selected data**

**2 - Bind the cluster output (`kmeans_run$cluster`) to the subset data table**

**3 - `ggplot` by location where `color=cluster`**

I can do this in r fairly easily

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  lat = rnorm(150, mean = 30, sd = 5),
  lon = rnorm(150, mean = 10, sd = 5),
  iris[, 1:4]))

km <- kmeans(df[, 3:4], 4)
df$cluster <- km$cluster

ggplot(df, aes(lon,
           lat,
           color=cluster)) +
         geom_point()
```

I have been butchering this useful [demo](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html) and it *kind of* works for the k-means but am struggling to get it to just run it with the one data set.

```
ui1 <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Selectable variables for k-means",
                         names(df[, 3:6]), selected = names(df[, 3:6])),
      numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9),
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))))

server1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({df[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]})
  
  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
    
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui1, server1)
```

Many thanks, even the first part of the answer would be ace!

Answer (score 0):

```
 clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })
  
  output$ggplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(contin_data,aes(x=bin_median_lon,
                           y=bin_median_lat))+geom_point(colour=clusters()$cluster)},
    height = 700, width = 700)
}
```

different data but get the idea